# Is there a possible way to execute sql in QTP using WITH clause?

Tags: oracle, qtp

I've connected to Oracle Database using QTP and I am trying to execute a statement using `WITH` clause in the query, but I am unable to achieve the same.

Sample query :

```
WITH VIEW123 AS
(SELECT * FROM <TABLE1>)
SELECT * FROM VIEW123
```

Note:

The above mentioned query is just an example. I am using the with clause, since I would be using the query inside the `view123` in multiple areas in the query.

Would appreciate any solution provided.

Comment: What is the problem/error? And what is the exact code.

Comment: @Robert Hey, don´t be so picky. Isn´t it enough to throw in some (any) code and ask for help without specifying the exact problem? :-O

Answer (score 1):

```
SQL>WITH VIEW123 AS (SELECT * FROM DUAL) SELECT * FROM VIEW123

DUMMY
X
```

Answer (score 0):

I tried creating a database checkpoint , in the following way:
Insert->Database checkpoint->Specify SQL statement manually ->
Under connection string , i entered the following connection string

Driver={Microsoft ODBC for Oracle};Server=(DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=TCP)(HOST=usadc-sdbxp01)(PORT=1545))(CONNECT_DATA=(SID=DBILSU)));Uid=shruthic;Pwd=admin@123;

Under SQL Statement, I entered the following:
WITH VIEW123 AS
(SELECT * FROM ENTERPRISE)
SELECT * FROM VIEW123

When I clicked Finished button, the following error message was thrown.
"The specified query could not be executed. Do you want to redefine your settings"
Details->Operation is not allowed when the object is closed.

Note:When I tried creating a database checkpoint with the same connection strings , but with the sql query "select * from enterprise", I was able to get result for the same.